# change radio button and then read() with mechanize (python)

Tags: python, html, automation, radio-button, mechanize

I would like to change the value of a radio button and then retrieve the html of the following website:
http://www.androidpit.com/en/android-market/recommendations-list?rid=NEWCOMER_RATING

I'm new to python but I figure that you use mechanize to do the job. This site has been of tremendous help but right now I am stuck.

Changing the value of the Radio button seems to work out nicely:

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("http://www.androidpit.com/en/android-market/recommendations-list?rid=NEWCOMER_RATING")
br.select_form(nr=5)
print br.find_control(name='timeFilter').value
br.form['timeFilter'] = ['TODAY']
br.select_form(nr=5)
print br.find_control(name='timeFilter').value
```

.....
however, I have trouble reading the final html.
If I manually change the Button and reload the page, the page source changes. however, if I try this with mechanize, the value of the radio button seems to be set back to its default value and what I get using read() is the old source.

```
br.submit()
br.reload()
br.select_form(nr=5)
print br.find_control(name='timeFilter').value
```

Having read a lot of posts here I tried various things but it's just returning the first page over and over again.
Since I am really new to all this, there is a good chance that I'm getting some basic stuff wrong.
Any help would be highly apprechiated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try finding the button that is necessary to click and submit the form using

> br.submit(name='ct100$ct100$')

insert the name of the button needed to be clicked, this one I put in won't work, it is just an example

Answer (score 0):

you should set your header use livehttp header extension to analyze the header and then set the header using addheaders function